# cookie plugin grails - cookie is null

Tags: grails, cookies, groovy

with Grails' cookie plugin, which is correctly installed, I want to set a cookie:

```
response.setCookie("username", "cookiename", 1000)
```

this method "setCookie" is underlined, so in the IDE it means it could not be found,
this version doesn't work either

```
def cookieService

cookieService.set(response, "username", "cookiename", 1000)
```

this line says, the cookie is null

```
println(cookieService.get("username"))
```

What did I miss? I was wondering it has something to do with that grails is running on a server and it performs a task on the client side (which usually is done by JS).

Comment: i just want to add that the line cookieService.get("username") is spelled correctly in the code, the problem is not the typo with the "m"

Comment: fixed your typo for you.

Comment: this is solved, the thread can be deleted

Comment: @dan, you can answer your own question if you have solved it, that will help others with the same problem

Comment: @dan hi, can you answer  your question?

Comment: Sorry this is too long ago I have no idea anymore *D'oh*

Answer (score 0):

Dan: just add the following code to your config.groovy

```
com.studentuniverse.grails.plugins.cookie.services.CookieService.metaClass.setCookie = { response, name, value, maxAge ->
       def cookie = new javax.servlet.http.Cookie(name, value)
       cookie.setMaxAge(maxAge)
       cookie.setPath("/")
       response.addCookie(cookie)
}
```

you are getting null coz of the path.. This will solve ur issue :)